# What is the gesture name?

Tags: ios, gesture

How this gesture called in Xcode? Or how can I find this on the internet? Mail app use it to update mails. Many apps called it "Release to update".

Comment: try searching for ios Pull to Refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is "Pull to Refresh". You can find examples in Google.